# camel-cmis converting @ to %40

Tags: apache-camel

while i am passing cmis://http://mydocs.mic.com?username=admin&password=@d&!n2010) is the url. but its showing 
Failed to resolve endpoint: cmis://http://mydocs.mic.com?%21n2010%29&password=%40d&username=admin due to: Parsing exception!

camel is converting @ to %40 and ! to %21. Could you please help. how camel will retain the @ and ! symbles?

Thanks in adance 
sankar

Answer (score 0):

The Camel documentation explains about this

See this page, how to configure endpoints and about passwords

- http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-configure-endpoints.html